# EF Core Second level ThenInclude missworks

Tags: entity-framework, include, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Assume having these models first:

`Method` that has one `OriginalCode`
`OriginalCode` that has many `Mutant`s
`Mutant` that has many `ParseSubTree`s

Now when querying on `Method` I want the other being loaded. So I have the following:

```
Method targetMethod = dBContext.Methods
            .Include(me => me.OriginalCode)
                .ThenInclude(oc => oc.Mutants)
            .FirstOrDefault(me => me.Id == id);
```

and the next step is to include additionally the `ParseSubTree`. But the thing is that I can't access it. See the following Image:

[image: mu is a list except object reference]

the problem is "mu is a list instead of being an object reference"!

Where is my mistake!

TG.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This is a known Intellisense issue with the `ThenInclude` overload for collection type navigation properties, tracked by the [Completion missing members of lambda parameter in fault tolerance case #8237](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/8237) Roslyn GitHub issue.

Until it gets fixed, simply type the name of the property and it will compile successfully and work as expected.

```
.ThenInclude(mu => mu.ParseSubTrees)
```

**Update:** Now it's even specifically mentioned in the [Including multiple levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#including-multiple-levels)
 section of the EF Core documentation:

> **Note**
>
> Current versions of Visual Studio offer incorrect code completion options and can cause correct expressions to be flagged with syntax errors when using the `ThenInclude` method after a collection navigation property. This is a symptom of an IntelliSense bug tracked at https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/8237. It is safe to ignore these spurious syntax errors as long as the code is correct and can be compiled successfully.

Comment: 2019 and still not fixed... :-( Thank you for saving my time, sir! :-) <3

Comment: @WoIIe *Milestone: **Backlog***. Which means not even scheduled to be fixed :-(

Comment: Came here today to find this gem. Still not fixed in 2019 16.3.9.

Comment: 2020 and not fixed, but apparently fixed in VS16.5, which is currently in pre-release. I spent hours on this convinced by DbContext was wrong... I guess I have come to completely rely on intellisense. Oh and it looks like they have taken it *off* the "Including Multiple Levels" section of the EF Core doco, which would have saved me hours.

Answer (score 2):

In my case there was a conflict between the namespaces System.Data.Entity and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore. Just delete the first using line.