# Many to Many List Querying in EF, .Net CORE 2.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to be able to associate n users with a particular accomplishment.

```
public class VPTSDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Accomplishment> Accomplishments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public VPTSDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) {}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserAccomplishment>().HasKey(ua => new { ua.AccomplishmentID, ua.UserID });
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserAccomplishment>().HasOne(ua => ua.Accomplishment).WithMany(u => u.UserAccomplishments).HasForeignKey(ua => ua.AccomplishmentID);
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserAccomplishment>().HasOne(ua => ua.User).WithMany(u => u.UserAccomplishments).HasForeignKey(ua => ua.UserID);
    }

}
```

User.cs

```
public class User
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserAccomplishment> UserAccomplishments { get; set; }
}
```

Accomplishment.cs

```
    public class Accomplishment
{
    [Key]
    public int AccomplishmentID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserAccomplishment> UserAccomplishments { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my linking table:
    public class UserAccomplishment
    {

```
    [Required]
    public int AccomplishmentID { get; set; }
    public virtual Accomplishment Accomplishment { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

}
```

How can I get back all accomplishments, including the user model?

I have tried the following:

```
public List<Accomplishment> GetAll()
{
    return dbContext.Accomplishments.Include(ua => ua.UserAccomplishments).ToList();
}
```

This is returning the users (in this case 2, 3 and 9), but I need the user's information as well.

```
[{"accomplishmentID":1,"title":"Test Accomplishment","userAccomplishments":[{"accomplishmentID":1,"userID":2,"user":null},{"accomplishmentID":2,"userID":3,"user":null},{"accomplishmentID":2,"userID":9,"user":null}]}]
```

How can I get the user's information?

FYI, User isn't available in the ThenInclude:

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

Comment: [Loading Related Data - Eager Loading - Including multiple levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data), e.g. `Include(ua => ua.UserAccomplishments).ThenInclude(ua => ua.User)`

Comment: Hey @Ivan Stoev, I've tried that, but User isn't available in the ThenInclude()...I have added a screenshot to my original post.

Comment: I don't understand the -1 vote, what information should I provide that will be helpful to solve my question?

Comment: Hey @ews2001, So you trust the Intellisense and not the official documentation or SO people :) Anyway, see [EF Core Second level ThenInclude missworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45658411/ef-core-second-level-theninclude-missworks/45658984#45658984).

Comment: You most likely didn't add the requisite navigation property to your join class, i.e. `public User User { get; set; }`.

Comment: @IvanStoev, actually I do have the User in my join class, I added that to my answer.  It's not that I trust Intellisense over you, it's just that when I add User as you specify, then I get the error: 'bool' does not contain a definition for 'User' and no extension method 'User' accepting a first argument of type 'bool' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

Comment: I got it to work!! Here is the solution, thank you Chris Pratt and Ivan Stoev!  Feel free to post this as the answer and I'll give you guys the credit...

Comment: public List<Accomplishment> GetAll()
        {
            var accomplishments = dbContext.Accomplishments.Include(u => u.UserAccomplishments).ThenInclude(ua => ua.User) ;
            return new List<Accomplishment>(accomplishments);