# Entity Framework include collection/reference where

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I'm trying to select the latest version of all my clients and load each object with the latest version of their respective payments and the payments respective segment name.

It's a .net Core 2.0 project.

The controller is using:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using CBFU.Data;
using CBFU.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

A client is created with no foreign keys.

A payment is created with af the foreign keys: `ClientId` and `SegmentId`.

A segment is created with no foreign keys.

I'm thinking something like:

```
var clients = _context.Clients
    .Where(client => client.IsLatest == 1)
    .Include(client => client.Payments
        .Select(payment => payment.IsLatest == 1)
            .Select(payment => payment.Segment))
    .ToList();
```

But that does not work. Below I've listed af few of the things I tried and if it worked. I've no examples with `.ThenInclude` as my intelliSense does not respond to it.

```
// 1 This works: Loading payments into clients
var clients = _context.Clients
    .Where(client => client.IsLatest == 1)
    .Include(client => client.Payments)
    .ToList();

// 2 This does NOT work: Loading payment with IsLatest == 0 into clients
var clients = _context.Clients
    .Where(client => client.IsLatest == 1)
    .Include(client => client.Payments
        .Select(p => p.IsLatest == 1))
    .ToList();

// 3 This does NOT work: Loading segment into payments into clients
var clients = _context.Clients
    .Where(client => client.IsLatest == 1)
    .Include(client => client.Payments
        .Select(p => p.Segment == 1))
    .ToList();
```

Both 2 and 3 gives the same error:

> The property expression 'client => {from Payment payment in client.Payments select ([payment].IsLatest == 1)}' is not valid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'.For more information on including related data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.
>   Source =< Cannot evaluate the exception source>

My classes looks as follows:

```
public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int IsLatest { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
}

public class Payment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Client Client { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Client")]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }

    public Segment Segment { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Segment")]
    public int SegmentId { get; set; }

    public int IsLatest { get; set; }
}

public class Segment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filtered `Include`s were never supported in pre EF Core, and (as of current v2.0) are still not supported by EF Core. EF Core 2.0 introduced [Model-level query filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/), but they apply for all queries and have to be specifically turned off when not needed. Also are not flexible enough to handle dynamic query level filtering.

What you can do though is to utilize a combination of the so called *navigation property fixup*, eager loading and filtering loaded entities techniques described in the [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) section of the documentation:

```
var clientQuery = _context.Clients
    .Where(client => client.IsLatest == 1);

var clients = clientQuery.ToList();

clientQuery
    .SelectMany(c => c.Payments)
    .Include(p => p.Segment)
    .Where(p => p.IsLatest == 1)
    .Load();
```

Comment: This will take two trips to the DB, right? One on .ToList() and one on .Load()

Comment: @Vlad274 Correct. But note that EFC eager loading of collection navigation properties also uses separate db trips (as opposed to monster union SQL query in EF6).

Comment: That works. Thank you very much :-) 

My biggest mistake here was thinking that Core 2.0 was running on EF6.

Could you help my to where you found this? I haven't been able to to find anything like this.

I'm a little disappointed in the form, so I tried:

`var clients = _context.Clients
.Where(client => client.IsLatest == 1)
                    .SelectMany(client => client.Payments
                        .Select(p => p.Segment))
                .ToList();`
That does not work!

Comment: You can't find this directly. It's based on different parts described in the Loading Related Data link. Navigation property fix up is mentioned in a Tip under Eager Loading. The filtering part is based on Explicit Loading - Querying related entities - *You can also filter which related entities are loaded into memory.* example. All this combined with experiments because every EF Core release is changing behaviors. Btw, speaking about eager loading, the EFC way is to use `ThenInclude` rather than `Select` as it was in EF6. But there is Intellisense issue not showing members, so you have to ...

Comment: ... type them manually - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45658411/ef-core-second-level-theninclude-missworks/45658984#45658984

Comment: From what you are writing that we also can't use .Where with .ThenInclude. Correct?

Could you please show me how to go 1 level deeper with an ICollection and the .Where method?

E.g. if had to use .Where on Segment: `.Where(s => s.IsLatest == 1)`. From there on I should be able to extrapolate any further layers.

Comment: Correct - see the beginning of the answer: *Filtered Includes are not supported*. If it was possible, I wouldn't suggest a workaround (what basically the answer is).