# Including related entities across a many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a many-to-many relationship set up with Entity Framework like this:

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }

    public ICollection<StudentClass> StudentClasses { get; set; }
}

public class Class
{
    public int ClassId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }

    public ICollection<StudentClass> StudentClasses { get; set; }
}

public class StudentClass
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }

    public int ClassId { get; set; }
    public Class Class { get; set; }
}
```

This works great, and I'm trying to get Students, but also get their related Classes. I have this:

```
var studentsWithClasses = await _dbContext.Students
    .Include(s => s.StudentClasses)
    .ToListAsync();
```

This gets me the StudentId and ClassId in the collection of StudentClasses, but the Class object is null. But I'd like to access data in the Class object so that I can see all the Students Class' Name and Location.

Is there a way to include that as well, or do I need to make a separate database call?

Comment: `Student` cannot be `null` with this query. And to get `Class` populated, you need `ThenIncude(sc => sc.Class)`

Comment: @IvanStoev - I can't do `ThenInclude(sc => sc.Class)` because the `StudentClasses` object is a collection

Comment: Yes, you can. See [EF Core Second level ThenInclude missworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45658411/ef-core-second-level-theninclude-missworks/45658984#45658984). Now specifically mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) - the **Note** under [Including multiple levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#including-multiple-levels)

Comment: You're right, that does work. Intellisense doesn't pick it up though for some reason, but it works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a string `Include` (be careful, intellisense won't tell you if the property actually exists or not).

```
var studentsWithClasses = await _dbContext.Students
    .Include("StudentClasses.Class")
    .ToListAsync();
```