# How can I use ThenInclude on a 3rd level off of a many to many object?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, many-to-many, intellisense

I have this query:

```
IQueryable<Comment> comments = _commentRepo.Comments
            .Include(c => c.CommentStaff)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.StaffOffices)
            .Where(c => c.CommentAuditId == auditId)
            .OrderByDescending(c => c.CommentDate).Take(3);
```

StaffOffices is a many to many bridge lookup POCO that looks like this:

```
[Table("staff_office")]
public class StaffOffice
{
    [Column("staff_office_staff_id")]
    public short ID { get; set; }
    public Staff Staff { get; set; }

    [Column("staff_office_office_id")]
    public short OfficeID { get; set; }
    public Office Office { get; set; }
}
```

I need the Office Objects to be populated by this query.

So I am trying this:

[image]

So as you can see, Office is not popping up in the Intellisense for my ThenInclude off of StaffOffices.

How can I get this to work?
Does this need to be defined in the AppContext Model with fluent API?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EF Core Second level ThenInclude missworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45658411/ef-core-second-level-theninclude-missworks)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it works even though it is not shown in intellisense. You could try it. Also if you need staff data you will have to include StaffOffices again.

```
IQueryable<Comment> comments = _commentRepo.Comments
            .Include(c => c.CommentStaff)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.StaffOffices)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Office)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.StaffOffices)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Staff)
            .Where(c => c.CommentAuditId == auditId)
            .OrderByDescending(c => c.CommentDate).Take(3);
```

If you choose comment staff repo, many to many level will be second level. Although order by might be tricky to do straight away. You will have to then order by and take from comments variable.

For ex:

```
var comments = _commentStaffRepo.CommentStaff
            .Include(c => c.StaffOffices)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Office)
            .Include(c => c.StaffOffices)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Staff)
            .Include(c => c.Comments)
            .Where(c => c.Comments.Any(co => co.CommentAuditId == auditId))
            .Select(c => c.Comments);
comments = comments.OrderByDescending(c => c.CommentDate).Take(3);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue, IntelliSense does not work with multiple levels. You just type `Office`, it will build successfully.

You can refer the following bugs.

[8237](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/8237), [9374](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9374) and [4117](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/4117).

Comment: Yep - Thanks! - If  I type this it compiles and red squiggly goes away.
Trying to see if I can finish up the rest of the solution now:)

Comment: @Sam Sure, let me know if you need help

Comment: @Sam it worked for u right? If yes could you please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Vivek and comment above.

Here is my Component Invoke method now:

```
public IViewComponentResult Invoke(int auditId)
    {
        IQueryable<Comment> comments = _commentRepo.Comments
            .Include(c => c.CommentStaff)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.StaffOffices).ThenInclude(so => so.Office)
            .Where(c => c.CommentAuditId == auditId)
            .OrderByDescending(c => c.CommentDate).Take(3);

        CommentVM commentVM = new CommentVM
        {
            AuditId = auditId,
            Comments = comments
        };

        return View(commentVM);
    }
```

I did another level ThenInclude:

```
.ThenInclude(c => c.StaffOffices).ThenInclude(so => so.Office)
```

Here is the snippet in the Razor that lays it out:

```
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <i>@comment.CommentStaff.FullName </i>
                                @if (comment.CommentStaff.StaffOffices.Count() > 1)
                                {
                                <span>@($" ({string.Join(", ", from o in comment.CommentStaff.StaffOffices select o.Office.OfficeOrganizationCd)})")</span>
                                }
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                @comment.CommentDate
                            </div>
                        </div>
```