# EF Core nested ThenInclude

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nested, entity-framework-core

I am using EntityFramework (EF) Core and ASP.NET core.

My model is as:

```cs
class Zoo
{
    public ICollection<Animal> Animals {set; get;}
}

class Animal
{
    public ICollection<Dog> Dogs {set; get;}
}

class Dog
{
    public ICollection<Shepherd> Shepherds {set; get;}
}
```

(This is not exactly how my model is defined, the example is close enough, hope it can simply show the nested relation.)

---

### Question

I would like to query a `Zoo` with a given `id`, and include `Animals`, `Dogs`, and `Shepherds` in the result. I have:

```cs
var animals = await context.Zoo
                    .Include(zoo => zoo.Animals)
                    .ThenInclude(animal => animal.Dogs) // operates on the Animal type
                    .FirstAsync(zoo => zoo.ID = id)
```

Any thoughts on how I can add `Shepherds`?

(*Note: I am aware of [this](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/4716#issuecomment-193471074) discussion on Github, though not sure how to leverage the suggested method to **go deeper in my nested relational-model***.)

Comment: Can you chain another ThenInclude? What's the data type of `x` in your last call?

Comment: Another `ThenInclude` operates on `ICollection<Dogs>`.

Comment: Isn't that what you're after? Adding `.ThenInclude(dog => dog.Shepherds)`?

Comment: First `ThenInclude` operates on `ICollection<Animal>`, so why the next `ThenInclude` operating in `ICollection<Dogs>` should be a problem? In case Intellisense is not showing it, just type it and will work.

Comment: Sorry, the question was confusing (please see the commend in the question); the first `ThenInclude` operats on `Animal`, if I add a second `ThenInclude`, it one operates on `ICollection<Dog>`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EF Core Second level ThenInclude missworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45658411/ef-core-second-level-theninclude-missworks)

Comment: Yes, thank you. That is the issue I am facing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to include the `dog.Sheperds` in the result, then just continue with the `ThenInclude` calls:

```
var animals = await context.Zoo
    .Include(zoo => zoo.Animals)
        .ThenInclude(animal => animal.Dogs)
            .ThenInclude(dog => dog.Sheperds)
    .FirstAsync(zoo => zoo.ID = id);
```

Each of the [`ThenInclude()` calls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.theninclude?view=efcore-3.1) operates on the previous result, so you can use this to go deeper. It’s only `Include()` that resets back to the original level. So if you wanted to include multiple collections from `Animal` for example, then you would have to start at the beginning again for those:

```
var animals = await context.Zoo
    .Include(zoo => zoo.Animals)
        .ThenInclude(animal => animal.Dogs)
            .ThenInclude(dog => dog.Sheperds)
    .Include(zoo => zoo.Animals)
        .ThenInclude(animal => animal.Cats)
    .FirstAsync(zoo => zoo.ID = id);
```

Note: When using `ThenInclude`, IntelliSense will often give you the autocomplete hints for the first overload that operates on `TPreviousProperty` instead of `IEnumerable<TPreviousProperty>`. If you just continue and use the correct overload, it will eventually figure it out though and it will not stop you from compiling it properly.

Comment: I was confused by the Intellisense; @Ivan's comment: > In case Intellisense is not showing it, just type it and will work